# Error using Specs2 with FluentLenium Api

Tags: scala, webdriver, playframework-2.0, specs2

I use Scala 2.10, Specs2 13.1-SNAPSHOT and the FluentLenium Api provided by Play2 Framework 2.1.

I have this line of code in my `IntegrationSpec` file, finding a child element (according to FluentLenium spec):

```
browser.find(".myClass").find("#mySubElement") must haveSize(1)
```

That line leads to the following compilation error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentList[_ <: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement]
required: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentList[?0(in value $anonfun)] where type ?0(in value $anonfun) <: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement
Note: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement >: ?0, but Java-defined class FluentList is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ?0`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

Is it a kind of...incompatibilty Scala/Java due to generics?? or a normal behaviour that I didn't figure out?

This line however (omitting any matcher), well compiles:

```
browser.find(".myClass").find("#mySubElement")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `haveSize` matcher require the element being matched to have an `org.specs2.data.Sized` typeclass in scope. The corresponding typeclass for java collections is:

```
implicit def javaCollectionIsSized[T <: java.util.Collection[_]]: Sized[T] = 
  new Sized[T] {
    def size(t: T) = t.size()
  }
```

I suspect that type inference here is the issue and you could try to tame it with the following ugly code:

```
browser.find(".myClass").
        find("#mySubElement").
        asInstanceOf[FluentList[FluentWebElement]] must haveSize(1)
```

Or maybe

```
browser.find(".myClass").
        find("#mySubElement").
        asInstanceOf[Collection[_]] must haveSize(1)
```

Or

```
import scala.collection.convert.JavaConverters._

browser.find(".myClass").
        find("#mySubElement").
        asScala must haveSize(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric :) Issue resolved! Indeed, inference was not obvious for the scala compiler.

Comment: Which solution did you end up with?

Comment: I chose the first one (matter of taste? :)) since the three are pretty. I think I understood the problem: When chaining find methods, the second one returns a FluentList without any parameter type! Its class definition is nevertheless: public class FluentList<E extends FluentWebElement> , so as you mentioned, javaCollectionIsSized expects an invariant TYPED collection, not a raw one (even containing variance), hence the compiler complaint. What do you think about?

Comment: That looks pretty similar to some issues I had with Mockito.

Comment: Actually, this error occurs with any type of `MustMatcher`. I don't figure out the reason but I'm pretty sure that the issue is linked with the implicit methods building a `MustExpectable`.