# Scala and strangeness with Generics

Tags: scala, generics

I came across this type mismatch that I don't understand:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentList[_<:org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement]
required: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentList[?0(in value $anonfun)] where type ?0(in value $anonfun) <: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement
Note: org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement >: ?0, but Java-defined class FluentList is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ?0`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

Indeed, it is precised that the "found" value is of type:

`org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentList[_<:org.fluentlenium.core.domain.FluentWebElement]` => variant type parameter

I couldn't represent a situation like this, where a "found" value is a variant type parameter. I tried this simple snippet code:

```
public class CarList<E extends Car> implements Collection<E> { // written in Java
   //overriden methods from Collection here
}

public class Car{} // written in Java

public Ferrari extends Car{} //written in Java

object Main extends App {  

   val carList: CarList[Car] = new CarList[Car]

   val l: CarList[Ferrari] = carList

}
```

Compilation Error occuring is very similar:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : app.CarList[app.Car]     //but in this case, logically it's an invariant type: Car
required: app.CarList[app.Ferrari]
Note: app.Car >: app.Ferrari, but Java-defined class CarList is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: app.Ferrari`. (SLS 3.2.10)
val l: CarList[Ferrari] = carList
                                     ^
```

How to modify my code snippet to end up exactly with:

- the same kind of error than `FluentList`'s one (precising a variant type parameter in the "found" value):
  `found   : app.CarList[_ :> app.Car]`
- with the same advice from compiler:
  `You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as _ >:`

so that I can figure out what might be the origin of the issue?

Comment: Tried simply `new FluentList[FluentWebElement]` ? Mind pasting the FluentList constructor signature?

Comment: @pedrofurla Yes, of course it would resolve the issue, but I'm trying to understand the real cause of an issue like this one :) `FluentList` is written in Java and constructor's signature is: `FluentList(java.util.Collection<E> listFiltered)`

Comment: I see, your doubt is actual about type variance.

Comment: @pedrofurla Yes, indeed

Comment: @pedrofurla I updated my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In your java example it seems you have reversed two things. You can not assign a list of cars to a list of Ferraris.

With that in mind I interpreted the snippet like this:

```
class CarList[E <: Car]

class Car
class Ferrari extends Car

object Main extends App {

  val carList = new CarList[Ferrari]

  // this now throws a compiler error
  val l: CarList[Car] = carList
}
```

The compiler error is as follows:

```
type mismatch;
found: CarList[Ferrari] required: CarList[Car]
Note: Ferrari <: Car, but class CarList is invariant in type E.
You may wish to define E as +E instead.
```

So the compiler actually helps us. This definition:

```
class CarList[E <: Car]
```

tells the compiler we have a list of things that extend `Car`.

However, that doesn't tell the compiler that `CarList[Ferrari]` also extends `CarList[Car]`. In order to tell the compiler that's the case we need to make `E` covariant with `+`.

Thus to solve the error we could do two things:

1. Define `CarList` as `CarList[+E]`, saying you don't care what's in them, but if `A` extends `B` then `CarList[A]` can be considered to extend `CarList[B]`
2. Define `CarList` as `CarList[+E <: Car]`, saying the same as 1. but with the extra restraint on the type of `E` in that it must be a `Car`.

[This question about variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question) might give additional information.

Comment: Sorry but my question was not: "how to solve it?" since I well master covariance/contravariance. My question was: "How to modify my code snippet to end up exactly with the same kind of error?", meaning I would like to come  across an error informing: "found   : `app.CarList[_ <: app.Car]   // I would like to come across this line
required: app.CarList[app.Ferrari]
Note: app.Car >: app.Ferrari, but Java-defined class CarList is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: app.Ferrari`. (SLS 3.2.10)`
I want to see a "found" with a variant parameter `:>`

Comment: You are totally right. I read the question wrong. Interesting question though!

Comment: No problem :) I spent all day long to search for an explanation ... I can't see one :(

Comment: You can easily reproduce this issue. You may look at my previous post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970301/error-using-specs2-with-fluentlenium-api .  Whatever the "Specs2" Matcher used, error occurs; for instance:  `browser.find(".myClass").find("#mySubElement") must_==(null)`. Solving it is pretty easy but figuring out WHY is another game :)

Comment: Damn, that took away the rest of my evening, haha. I could not reproduce that either. The wildcard error that you get with this snippet: `val x:CarList[_ <: Car] = (???):CarList[_ >: Car] ` is very similar. To get the error the other way around `_ <: Car` is doable as well. Apparently you found a construction were a type is both `CarList[X <: Car]` and `CarList[X >: Car]`. I don't know the precedence rules for the compiler, but it's showing information from the last one of these types.

Comment: :) I would say one thing: "Compiler, please blow into the breathalyser"  ;)